# Maven Archetype change in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-archetype

I created a maven project using archetype j2ee-simple in IntelliJ IDEA (2016.1.3). Now is there a way, I can change the archetype for this project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's no matter of IntelliJ IDEA.

Once a maven project is created, whether with archetype or "blank" (I mean with minimum POM), you are free to add dependencies and plugins as you want.

But you can't apply another archetype to a created project.